# how to store session data in spring 3

Tags: spring, session, store

I am using spring 3 mvc, annotation based.

I am storing session data using @sessionattribute and @Modelattribute annotation using at class level and method level.

It works fine. BUT

The http request attributes values  with the same name as session object attributes, are being overridden in session object.

How to avoid this ? Now i have to switch to traditional   session.getAttribute   way of  managing session data with is not impressive in spring world.

What is the best practice to store and retrieve session data in controllers  and views?

Any help?

Comment: Can you give us small code example of 'session object with same name being overwritten' and clarify what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Here is what My code sample is...( excuse me for bad formatting...)

@Controller

@SessionAttributes({ "user" })

@RequestMapping("/login")

public class LoginController extends SuperController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView login(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("loginForm") LoginForm loginForm,
        BindingResult bindingResult, HttpSession session, Model model) {

                    // Adding user object to session after login.
                    modelAndView.addObject("user", user );
```

@Controller

@SessionAttributes({ "suser" })

@RequestMapping("/user")

public class UserController extends SuperController{

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createTeamMember", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createTeamMember(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm"),  MemberUserForm memberUserForm,  BindingResult bindingResult, @ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
```

memberUserForm.getFirstName(); //  First name of the new team member.

user.getFirstName(); // First Name of the logged in user( not same as above).

Since I am using @sessionAttributes, user.firstName is being overridden with memberUserForm.getFirstName() by spring before it calls createTeamMember which I dont intent to do....